# Add computed metadata to catalog for dexterity object (plone 4)

Tags: plone, zope

I want to create a catalog metadata with a computed string. So following [Aspeli's book](https://www.packtpub.com/professional-plone-4-development/book) and [the developer manual](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/custom-indexing-strategies) I proceeded to create an indexer:

```py
# indexer.py
@grok.adapter(Entry, name='bind_representation')
@indexer(Entry)
def bindIndexer(context):
    print str(IBindRepresentable(context))
    return str(IBindRepresentable(context))
```

and register the index with genericSetup:

```xml
<!-- profiles/default/catalog.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_catalog" meta_type="Plone Catalog Tool">

  <index name="bind_representation" meta_type="ZCTextIndex">
                  <!-- I tried with meta_type="FieldIndex" too -->
    <indexed_attr value="bind_representation"/>

    <!-- copied from other text metadata -->
    <extra name="index_type" value="Okapi BM25 Rank"/>
    <extra name="lexicon_id" value="plaintext_lexicon"/>
  </index>
</object>
```

The problems are: (1) only the index is registered, not the metadata, and (2) After reindex all the zodb, bind_representation still doesn't find any entry to index, even when they are.

The examples cited only deal with pre-existent indexes, so I'm not sure about the content of catalog.xml. **bindIndexer** seems not to be called at all, since its print statement is never executed. I copied **bindIndexer** to entry.py too, to get sure it wasn't being ignored, but still nothing.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- In order to add a new metadata, you have to use this syntax:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_catalog" meta_type="Plone Catalog Tool">
    ...
     <column value="bind_representation"/>
</object>
```

2a- you are adapting your content class, you should adapt your content interface (IEntry most likely).

2b- you are using a [ZCTextIndex](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/ZCTextIndex): that index won't show you all entries anyway (even following the previous point) because it's based on a lexicon. You should probably use this instead (unless you have specific bounds):

```xml
<index name="bind_representation" meta_type="FieldIndex">
    <indexed_attr value="bind_representation"/>
</index>
```

More info:

- http://bluebream.zope.org/doc/1.0/manual/componentarchitecture.html#adapters
- http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2009/12/catalog

Comment: Thanks! <column ... /> registered the metadata. Regards (2), Entry is the schema (My bad, I ommited the I from all dexterity schemas): class Entry(form.Schema): ...

Comment: I see. Are you sure that your product is properly grokked? You could use the good old zcml registration as a test (http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/custom-indexing-strategies)

Comment: Added too, before sending the question. In configure.zcml: <adapter name="bind_representation" factory=".indexer.bindIndexer" />